# Python : fit a curve to a list of integers

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pixel

I have a list of integers.

```
intList = [96, 98, 120, 163, 158, 166, 201, 201, 159, 98, 93, 73, 77, 72]
```

These numbers represent the grey values of a strip of 14 pixels, I would like to fit a curve to the distribution and save the x location of the vertex.

For the sake of context: I'm really working with a (*much* larger) lists of lists, each list containing the grey value of a row of pixel from an image.  For each row of pixels, I would like to plot a curve to the data and append the x-location of the vertex to a growing list.  Each row of pixels will have some noise, but one and only one broad, clear peak of pixel intensity (sample image below)

[image: the image from which I am extracting data]

I have NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib, and pillow, but I don't know very much about the *many* functions found within each.  Can anybody point me towards a module or functions that can likely do this?

Comment: I know that using matlab there is a polyfit function that does what your trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fit a polynomial, e.g. quadratic, use `polyfit`:

```
from pylab import *

x = arange(len(intList))
p = polyfit(x, intList, 2)
a, b, c = p
x0 = -0.5*b/a # x coordinate of vertex

# plot
x = arange(len(intList))
plot(x, intList)
plot(x, polyval(p, x))
axvline(x0, color='r', ls='--')
```

[image: quadratic fit]

To fit a more complicated function, e.g. a Gaussian, you can use `curve_fit`:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# define function to fit
ffunc = lambda x, a, x0, s: a*exp(-0.5*(x-x0)**2/s**2)

# fit with initial guess a=100, x0=5, s=2
p, _ = curve_fit(ffunc, x, intList, p0=[100,5,2])

x0 = p[1] # location of the mean

# plot
plot(x, intList)
plot(x, ffunc(x, *p))
axvline(x0, color='r', ls='--')
```

[image: Gaussian fit]

(Although to fit a Gaussian you're probably better off directly calculating the mean and variance of the distribution.)

Comment: This was tremendously helpful, but can you clarify something for me?

I wasn't able to plot those graphs without prefacing `plot` with `pyplot.`, nowI am able to graph the gaussian distribution, but `pyplot.plot(x, polyval(p,x))` yields a `NameError: name 'polyval' is not defined`.

what exactly is polyval, and should python know what it is?  When plotting a gaussian curve, I had no trouble with ffunc in the same line `pyplot.plot(x, ffunc(x, *p))

Comment: Sure, `polyval` is a function in numpy (as are `arange` and `polyfit`). Notice that I have at the top the line `from pylab import *`, which pulls in various useful bits of numpy and matplotlib, giving a MATLAB-like interface which is handy for quick work. A popular alternative is to put `import numpy as np` and then use `np.polyval`, etc.